# create folder and pubish sap webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

i am new to this and this is my requirement.

i need to create a folder for my team and have reports available there instead of sharing them to my inbox.

we do have a BO admin team, so where should they create a folder and how I need to save/publish this report over there.

please help

Comment: The [BusinessObjects Board](https://bobj-board.org/) is another great resource for asking these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a network folder to which the user the SIA is running as (see below) and your team both have access.

[image]

Then choose "File System" as your destination when scheduling. We use a system user for the credentials in the schedule. You do not want to schedule with a regular user and then have your scheduled reports fail when that user gets disabled when they leave your company.

It is possible that you may not see "File System" in the list of destinations. If that is the case your admin team will need to add it as a valid destination within the system's AdaptiveJobServer (CMC -> Servers).

[image]